# Descobrir se item está em array

Tags: array, delphi, delphi-7

Como faço para checar se um item está em um *array*? Ex:

```
var 
Tabela : Array of String;
begin
Tabela[0] := 'Valor';
Tabela[1] := 'Value';
if Tabela[0] = 'Valor' then
// do wathever;
```

Esse seria o modo normal, mas em um *array* grande, isso demoraria muito checar todos os números. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essencialmente não tem muito o que fazer, você tem que verificar item por item. Dependendo do que você quer existem outras estruturas de dados que podem minimizar o tempo de busca.

Por outro lado, talvez o que você queira é só montar um *loop* para varrer todo o *array* com um `for in`:

```
var 
    Tabela : Array of String;
    Str : String;
begin
    Tabela[0] := 'Valor';
    Tabela[1] := 'Value';
    for Str in Tabela do
        if Str = 'Valor' then
            // do wathever;
end;
```

Acabei de descobrir que é muito difícil achar documentação oficial sobre o Delphi. Mas achei algumas coisas que falam sobre o `for in`.

- [Em português](http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-o-for-in/1587)
- [Em inglês](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/delphi_loops.htm)

Achei uma outra forma com `for` normal em [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246730/221800). Está varrendo todo o *array* da mesma forma porém manualmente indo de índice em índice:

```
function StringInArray(const Value: string; Strings: array of string): Boolean;
var I: Integer;
begin
    Result := True;
    for I := Low(Strings) to High(Strings) do
        if Strings[i] = Value then Exit;
    Result := False;
end;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/StringInArray.pas)

Answer (score 7):

Se você utiliza versões recentes do Delphi(*D2010.. XE*), existe a função [`MatchStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.StrUtils.MatchStr) que pode fazer esse trabalho por você. Porém, caso utilize versões mais antigas do Delphi(*D6, D7*) utiliza-se a função [`AnsiMatchStr`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=AnsiMatchStr), ambas as funções estão definidas na unit `StrUtils`.

Veja um exemplo de uso da função `MatchStr`:

```
Const
  Tabela : Array[0..4] of String = ('Valor', 'Valor1', 'Valor2', 'Valor3', 'Valor4');
begin
if MatchStr('Valor2', Tabela) then
  ShowMessage('Esse valor existe')
else
  ShowMessage('Não existe esse valor na matriz');
```